# ipython import matplotlib.pyplot showed that libGL.so.1 no such file

Tags: matplotlib, anaconda

Today when I used the command "import matplotlib.pyplot" in ipython,it showd the problem like that:
    `

### In [6]: import matplotlib.pyplot

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
----> 1 import matplotlib.pyplot

/root/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py in ()
    113 
    114 from matplotlib.backends import pylab_setup
--> 115 _backend_mod, new_figure_manager, draw_if_interactive, _show = pylab_setup()
    116 
    117 _IP_REGISTERED = None

/root/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/**init**.pyc in pylab_setup()
     30     # imports. 0 means only perform absolute imports.
     31     backend_mod = **import**(backend_name,
---> 32                              globals(),locals(),[backend_name],0)
     33 
     34     # Things we pull in from all backends

/root/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_qt5agg.py in ()
     14 
     15 from .backend_agg import FigureCanvasAgg
---> 16 from .backend_qt5 import QtCore
     17 from .backend_qt5 import QtGui
     18 from .backend_qt5 import FigureManagerQT

/root/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_qt5.py in ()
     24 
     25 from matplotlib.widgets import SubplotTool
---> 26 import matplotlib.backends.qt_editor.figureoptions as figureoptions
     27 
     28 from .qt_compat import (QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, _getSaveFileName,

/root/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/qt_editor/figureoptions.py in ()
     18 import matplotlib
     19 from matplotlib import cm, markers, colors as mcolors
---> 20 import matplotlib.backends.qt_editor.formlayout as formlayout
     21 from matplotlib.backends.qt_compat import QtGui
     22

/root/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/qt_editor/formlayout.py in ()
     54 
     55 from matplotlib import colors as mcolors
---> 56 from matplotlib.backends.qt_compat import QtGui, QtWidgets, QtCore
     57 
     58

/root/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/qt_compat.py in ()
    126     if QT_API == QT_API_PYQT5:
    127         try:
--> 128             from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
    129             _getSaveFileName = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getSaveFileName
    130         except ImportError:

ImportError: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    `

my python version is 

`Python 2.7.13 :: Anaconda 4.4.0 (64-bit)`

my os is 
`CentOS release 6.8 (Final)
Kernel \r on an \m`

I don't know how to deal with this problem
thanks

Answer (score 3):

Installing mesa libgl worked for me in case the env is ubuntu 16

```
sudo apt install libgl1-mesa-glx
```

[source](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/docker-images/issues/49#issuecomment-311556456)

Comment: works for me too (ubuntu 16.04 LTS, July 2018). thanks

Answer (score 1):

As discussed here, This solved the issue for me : 
https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/9954

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("tkagg")
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Comment: matplotlib.use("tkagg") result in error if one does not have tk backend installed. Now this works for me: matplotlib.use("Agg"). In either case, I think this is a workaround, rather than really fixing the issue. A couple other folks noted here and elsewhere that installation of meas libGL  solved the issue (without  the need of.use('Agg')) - the installation is at yum/rpm or apt-get system package level.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this problem as well with conda. What I ended up doing is as follow

```
#activate the environment
source activate myenv
#use pip instead of conda install
pip install matplotlib
```

Comment: i was just about to respond questioning how matplotlib was installed since I saw op using anaconda tag.
I also experienced similar error and I had to uninstall conda version of matplotlib and install it back via pip. It worked after that